# Stop waiting on MQGET to exit gracefully

Tags: c, ibm-mq

I am trying to write a function that is gracefully shutting down the program which is getting the messages from the queue.

The MQGET is started with MQGMO_WAIT option which suits me perfectly. However, I get an error when trying to issue another MQI call (MQCLOSE and MQDISC in this case).

The error is about gracefully closing the queue to exit the program. If the MQGET call is WAITing, then the MQCLOSE is causing error 2219.

Is there some kind of signal or MQI call to stop the MQGET call waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the new call-back feature in WMQ v7.1 rather than MQGET with wait.   Or shorten your wait to 1 or 2 seconds and loop over a "flag".